# How to use WLAN Channel 14 outside of Japan?

Tags: wireless-networking, regional-settings

I'm in Europe, I have a router and I have to test its UI.
When I set the *Region* to Japan and *Channel* to 14 my PC won't connect back to the router and I have to do a firmware reset.

In the office I have several various USB Wi-Fi sticks and notebooks but those can't connect either.

**Is using Channel 14 a hardware problem or a software problem?**
I would like to a solution that doesn't use another program. Only another device or proper driver is acceptable.

Comment: I disagree. WLAN channel 14 problems can occur all over the world, either with misconfigured hardware, or using the channel intentionally without approval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buy a Japanese Wi-Fi card.  And possibly find a place to test where you can't see any other Wi-Fi networks ever.

Some vendors sell "world mode" cards that automatically adjust their supported channels list for the country they find themselves in. When you associate to a given AP, it adopts the rules for the country code in the beacons of the AP. But when you first boot up or wake from sleep, it doesn't know what country it's in, so it might look at the beacons of any APs it sees in scans. If it decides to use the country code of the first AP it sees, and the first AP it sees is a Hungarian ETSI unit, it'll disable channel 14 if it ever supported it in the first place.

Channel 14 is kinda weird because it's Japan-only and even there, it has extra power restrictions that keep it from being useful for the latest modulations, as I recall. I seem to recall that it was only good for 802.11b only, not G or N.  So a lot of vendors don't bother supporting it anymore, not even for Japan.  It's just not worth the extra development/QA/maintenance/support/regulatory-certification costs for a channel that can only limp along at 11mbps.

Answer (score 1):

It's neither a hardware nor a software problem, but a regulatory one. Before you start digging around the settings of your computer or router, speak to the local agency regulating frequency concessions where you live and talk them into either extending the ISM allocation to the full ITU suggestion or obtain your own license for use of the 2483.5 to 2500.0 MHz band.

Alternately, I suppose you could argue that what you want to do is either a medical implant or a mobile satellite reception terminal, which is what the band is used for in most of Europe. I'm not certain of the power requirements for satellite terminals, but if you decide to implant the laptop (or router) in your thigh for medical purposes you'll have to reduce the mean transmitted power to a hundredth of what's common for 802.11 devices. I'm told capacity on experimental rocket launches is sometimes made available to universities, you might want to look into scoring some of that if you go for the mobile satellite service idea.

#### Edit:

While I don't read Hungarian and don't know how to check if there have been revisions to this, ITU Reolution 9, annex 2 is a frequency plan for Hungary. if you look at page 47 in the second column from the right, you will see the 2400 - 2483.5 MHz band is made available under 7 different use cases (I didn't look them up in particular, but see above), while the band from 2483.5 - 2500 MHz is available for two of the same and one additional use.

Comment: The normal solution is a Faraday cage. You're talking about a serious one, though: Wifi wavelengths are well under a meter. But within a properly designed Faraday cage, you're not bound by regulatory rules.

Comment: @MSalters "It's not illegal if you don't get caught"?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Consider any normal PC running at 2.5Ghz. That CPU is generating radio interference at band 14. It's perfectly legal though precisely because it's in a metal box. My company has an entire room isolated from <50Hz to >5Ghz, again legally, for such tests.

Comment: Ok, then! Hypothetically speaking, if legal considerations and interference wold not count, how could I use Channel 14?